# How to use PDF Sharp objects in my Migradoc document

Tags: watermark, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have an application that generates PDFs using the MigraDoc framework, however I have a requirement to add in a text driven watermark. I have found some examples of this being done using PDF Sharp [here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Watermark-sample.ashx), however I just cant seem t be able to figure out how this will integrate with my Migradoc `Document()` object I am rendering.

I have the following code:

```
    public byte[] render()
    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        CreateWaterMarks(document);

        // *****************************

        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);
        renderer.Document = this.document;
        renderer.RenderDocument();

        byte[] pdfContents = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            renderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, true);
            pdfContents = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return pdfContents;
    }
```

This method is what is called to render the MigraDoc document and pass it out as a byte array. The second line of code in here calls the following method which is not doing what I am looking for:

```
    void CreateWaterMarks(PdfDocument document)
    {
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        Document doc = this.document;

        MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
        docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

        XRect A4Rect = new XRect(0, 0, pageActiveWidth, pageActiveHeight);

        int pageCount = docRenderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < pageCount; idx++)
        {
            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 13, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);

            XSize size = gfx.MeasureString("Watermark", font);

            gfx.TranslateTransform(pageActiveWidth / 2, pageActiveHeight / 2);
            gfx.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(pageActiveHeight / pageActiveWidth) * 180 / Math.PI);
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-pageActiveWidth / 2, -pageActiveHeight / 2);

            XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;
            format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;

            XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));

            gfx.DrawString("Watermark", font, brush, new XPoint((pageActiveWidth - size.Width) / 2, (pageActiveHeight - size.Height) / 2), format);

            docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, idx + 1);
        }
    }
```

I was hoping that this would magically make these PDFSharp watermarks appear but alas I get nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I have this working using the following code:

```
    public byte[] render()
    {
        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);
        renderer.Document = this.document;

        renderer.RenderDocument();
        renderer.PrepareRenderPages();

        CreateWatermarks(renderer);

        byte[] pdfContents = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            renderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, true);
            pdfContents = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return pdfContents;
    }

    private void CreateWatermarks(PdfDocumentRenderer renderer)
    {
        int pages = renderer.DocumentRenderer.FormattedDocument.PageCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < pages; ++i)
        {
            var page = renderer.PdfDocument.Pages[i];

            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 27, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);

            XSize size = gfx.MeasureString("Watermark", font);

            gfx.TranslateTransform(pageActiveWidth / 2, pageActiveHeight / 2);
            gfx.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(pageActiveHeight / pageActiveWidth) * 180 / Math.PI);
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-pageActiveWidth / 2, -pageActiveHeight / 2);

            XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;
            format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;

            XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));

            gfx.DrawString("Watermark", font, brush, new XPoint((pageActiveWidth - size.Width) / 2, (pageActiveHeight - size.Height) / 2), format);

        }
    }
```